# Curriculum for developing with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to write a web site using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and Microsoft technologies. I'm studying it now, and enjoying it.

The web site is experimental, and will be used by me and my son in house, but of course I will want to grow it and let other people use it. It will be in Hebrew.

What other technologies do I need to study? One I'm sure of is C# 4.0 (and LINQ). But I'm not sure about ASP.Net 4.0 - Do I also need to study it? How about Html 5? Javascript? Entity framework? Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's my $0.02 worth of advice. I guess if your are going to expand this site at some point in the future you would have to add Enfity Framework 4 as well in terms of how you do your data access and JQuery since it comes out of the box with your MVC projects. Since you are developing it now you might as well add HTML5 to the list. With respect to ASP.NET 4 you might not need to if you're only doing this for your site. It's a pity that there aren't any mvc3 books our yet but you could either refer to blogs for newer material or if you don't mind use MVC2 books to help you along with u

Comment: Oh, there's more than enought material to sudy ASP.NET MVC 3. What I asked is what I need to study in addition to that.

Comment: Two resources I found for ASP.NET MVC 3.0 are: 
Book (Alpha Version) Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework at http://www.apress.com/microsoft/asp-net/9781430234043 
and online course titled " Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC 3 
" at http://www.pluralsight-training.net/